# How to create associative array in wrapping class

Tags: c#

I have made a array associative like this , and I know how to take get value from a dict with index 10

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int[]>>
    {
        {
            10, new Dictionary<string, int[]>
            {
                {"first", new[] {57, 57, 5, 0}},
                {"second", new[] {42, 58, 13, 8}}
            }
        },
        {
            40, new Dictionary<string, int[]>
            {
                {"first", new[] {4, 24, 5, 0}},
                {"second", new[] {42, 58, 23, 8}}
            }
        }
    };

foreach (var item in dict[10])
{
    foreach (var test in item.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test);   //This will show value with key 10                 
    }
};
```

after that I want to change this code to make my code more elegant and maintainable by wrapping the dict in class

First class

```
class DataContainer
{  
    public DataContainer() {}

    public int index { get; set; }
    public DataValue DataValue { get; set; }
}
```

Second class

```
class DataValue
{
    public DataValue()
    { 
        IntegerValues = new List<int>();
    }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<int> IntegerValues { get; set; }
}
```

after that I want to fill my data like I inserted in dict dictionary, but I confuse how to make it. I have tried with this below code.

```
public List<DataContainer> harakatSininilMabsutoh = new List<DataContainer>(){
    new DataContainer{index = 10 , DataValue = new List<DataValue>()
        {
            new DataValue{name = "first", IntegerValues = {9,55,18,11}},
            new DataValue{name = "second", IntegerValues = {5,54,18,11}},
        }
    }
}
```

But I got the error result after that I want to try to show a integervalue which has index = 10, but I got an error.

Comment: i want to show it integervalues with for each like i did in dict dictionary  but i confuse how to do it

Comment: How you tried to get integersvalues?

Comment: I don't know too about that

Comment: Take a look at C# indexers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Comment: No , this is what i mean
index = 10
first = 57,57,5,0
second = 42, 58, 13, 8

index = 40
 first = 4, 24, 5, 0
second = 42, 58, 23, 8

So i want to add 
first10 = 57,57,5,0
first40 = 4, 24, 5, 0
           ------------------- +
result     61 ,  81 , 10 ,0

second 10 = 42, 58, 13, 8
second 40 = 42, 58, 23, 8
result         -----------------------+
                   84, 116 , 36 , 18

Comment: You should be using a `Dictionary`, not a `List`, if you want to efficient look items up by their key.

Answer (score 0):

in your datacontainer class you have one Datavalue property. not a List.

```
class DataContainer
{  
    public DataContainer() {}

    public int index { get; set; }
    public DataValue DataValue { get; set; } //<-- only one Datavalue
}
```

but in your code below

```
public List<DataContainer> harakatSininilMabsutoh = new List<DataContainer>(){ 
    new DataContainer{index = 10 , DataValue = new List<DataValue>()
        {// ***DataValue is not a list****
            new DataValue{name = "first", IntegerValues = {9,55,18,11}},
            new DataValue{name = "second", IntegerValues = {5,54,18,11}},
        }
    }
}
```

you when you new up datacontainer, you are setting dataVlue to a List. if the above is what you want to do change your DataContainer class to

```
class DataContainer
{  
    public DataContainer() { DataValue = new List<DataValue>();}

    public int index { get; set; }
    public List<DataValue> DataValue { get; set; }
}
```

now you can do

```
var conatainer10 = harakatSininilMabsutoh.FirstOrDefault(container => container.index == 10);
           // if you want to loop

            foreach (var dataContainer in harakatSininilMabsutoh)
            {
                foreach (var dataValue in dataContainer.DataValue)
                {

                }
            }
```

Comment: How to foreach that ? (wanna show like i did in dict dictionary)
if dictionary i know how to show foreach (var item in dict[10])
{
    foreach (var test in item.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test);   //This will show value with key 10                 
    }
};

Comment: Can you show me how to add the (sum)
integer values in first name which has index 10 will be added by first name which has index 40
can you show me how to do it ?
if any body can i will mark your answer as accepting answer

Comment: No , this is what i mean
index = 10
first = 57,57,5,0
second = 42, 58, 13, 8

index = 40
 first = 4, 24, 5, 0
second = 42, 58, 23, 8

So i want to add 
first10 = 57,57,5,0
first40 = 4, 24, 5, 0
           ------------------- +
result     61 ,  81 , 10 ,0

second 10 = 42, 58, 13, 8
second 40 = 42, 58, 23, 8
result         -----------------------+
                   84, 116 , 36 , 18

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `harakatSininilMabsutoh [10]` ? if so, it's normal that is raises an error, you didn't define an index in your class, to get your dataContainer, you use this code :

```
var data = DataContainer.FirstOrDefault(d=>d.Index == 10);
```

now you can loop using this code :

```
foreach(intVal in data.IntegerValues)
{
// do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: yes I see that Can you show me how to add the (sum)
integer values in first name which has index 10 will be added by first name which has index 40
can you show me how to do it ?
if any body can i will mark your answer as accepting answer

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you question,refering to your post, do you want the sum of  {57, 57, 5, 0} +  {4, 24, 5, 0} ? so the sum is 119 + 33 = 152 ?

Comment: No , this is what i mean
index = 10
first = 57,57,5,0
second = 42, 58, 13, 8

index = 40
 first = 4, 24, 5, 0
second = 42, 58, 23, 8

So i want to add 
first10 = 57,57,5,0
first40 = 4, 24, 5, 0
           ------------------- +
result     61 ,  81 , 10 ,0

second 10 = 42, 58, 13, 8

Comment: Do u get it what i mean ?

Comment: It's not the same thing you asked in your post. Take a look to SelectMany, try an algorithm, and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want I have a complex solution with indexers. Here it is:

```
public class DataContainer
{
    private Dictionary<int, DataValue> _dataValues = new Dictionary<int, DataValue>();

    public DataValue this[int i] {
        get { return _dataValues[i]; }
        set { _dataValues[i] = value; }
    }

    public List<int> this[string i] {
        get {
            List<List<int>> l = new List<List<int>>();

            foreach (DataValue dv in _dataValues.Values) {
                try {
                    l.Add(dv[i]);
                }
                catch { }
            }

            return GetSum(l);
        }
    }

    public void Add(int index, DataValue val)
    {
        if (_dataValues.ContainsKey(index)) {
            _dataValues[index].Add(val);
        }
        else {
            _dataValues.Add(index, val);
        }
    }

    public List<int> GetSum(string index, params int[] indexes)
    {
        List<List<int>> l = new List<List<int>>();

        foreach (int i in indexes) {
            DataValue dv = this[i];

            try {
                l.Add(dv[index]);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        return GetSum(l);
    }

    private List<int> GetSum(List<List<int>> l)
    {
        if (l.Count > 0) {
            List<int> result = new List<int>();

            for (int j = 0; j < l.Count; j++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < l.FirstOrDefault().Count; z++) {
                    if (j == 0) {
                        result.Add(l[j][z]);
                    }
                    else {
                        result[z] += l[j][z];
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class DataValue
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<int>> _integerValues = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

    private string _name { get; set; }

    private List<int> _vals { get; set; }

    public List<int> this[string i] {
        get { return _integerValues[i]; }
        set { _integerValues[i] = value; }
    }

    public DataValue(string name, params int[] val)
    {
        _name = name;
        _vals = val.ToList();

        _integerValues.Add(_name, _vals);
    }

    public void Add(string index, List<int> val)
    {
        _integerValues.Add(index, val);
    }

    public void Add(string index, params int[] val)
    {
        _integerValues.Add(index, val.ToList());
    }

    public void Add(DataValue dataValue)
    {
        _integerValues.Add(dataValue._name, dataValue._vals);
    }
}
```

Here is how to create a collection:

```
DataContainer dc = new DataContainer();
dc.Add(10, new DataValue("first", 9, 55, 18, 11));
dc.Add(40, new DataValue("first", 9, 55, 18, 11));
dc.Add(10, new DataValue("second", 5, 54, 18, 11));
```

To get data:

```
List<int> intValues = dc[10]["first"];
```

To add a DataValue if DataContainer already exists:

```
cd[10].Add("third", 1, 2, 3, 4);
cd[10].Add("fourth", new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3, 4 });
cd[10].Add(new DataValue("fifth", 9, 55, 18, 11));
```

In this way your class are complicated but get and set are simple.
If you want to read more about indexers this is the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

To extract the sum of first you can do this:

```
List<int> vals = cd["first"];
```

Or:

```
List<int> vals = cd.GetSum("first", 10, 40);
```

Comment: No , this is what i mean
index = 10
first = 57,57,5,0
second = 42, 58, 13, 8

index = 40
 first = 4, 24, 5, 0
second = 42, 58, 23, 8

So i want to add 
first10 = 57,57,5,0
first40 = 4, 24, 5, 0
           ------------------- +
result     61 ,  81 , 10 ,0

second 10 = 42, 58, 13, 8
second 40 = 42, 58, 23, 8
result         -----------------------+
                   84, 116 , 36 , 18

Comment: Edited my answer. I updated my code with a new functionality that do what you want (I think). Now you can pass a text index and it return the sum of all elements that contains a `DataValue` with passed key. It's ok for you?

Comment: Another update. I added another method that you can use to do the sum between the index that you want.